# Scrapy duplicating results

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to parse various data items for each advert on a page such as https://www.pistonheads.com/classifieds?Category=used-cars&M=1044&ResultsPerPage=750

My code catches most of the items correctly. However, I'm running into two issues:

1. The output in the `Year` column is the same for every row. This occurs despite the `xpath` being exactly the same as that used in the `title` column which works correctly.
2. In my output, every row has a value for `Transmission` which can't be correct as not all adverts have this variable populated.

General comments about my code also appreciated. Perhaps I should be using `ItemLoaders` for this? (I haven't learnt how they work yet).

```
import scrapy
from datetime import date


class SuperScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ss22'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = 'https://www.pistonheads.com/classifieds?Category=used-cars&M=1044&ResultsPerPage=750'
        yield scrapy.Request(urls, callback = self.parse_data)

    def parse_data( self, response ):
        advert = response.xpath( '//*[@class="ad-listing"]')
        title = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="listing-headline"]//h3/text()' ).extract()
        year = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="listing-headline"]//h3/text()' ).extract()
        price = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="price"]/text()' ).extract()
        mileage = advert.xpath( './/*[contains(@class, "flaticon solid gauge-1")]/following-sibling::text()' ).extract()
        mileage = [item.strip() for item in mileage]
        mileage = [item.replace(',','') for item in mileage]
        mileage = [item.replace(' miles','') for item in mileage]
        timestamp = str(date.today()).split('.')[0] 
        timestamps = [timestamp for i in range(len(title))]
        model = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract()
        model = [item.replace("Used ","") for item in model]
        model = [item.replace(" cars for sale with PistonHeads","") for item in model]
        models = [model for i in range(len(title))]
        transmission = advert.xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "flaticon solid location-pin-4")]/following-sibling::text()').extract()
        transmission = [item.strip() for item in transmission]
        link = advert.xpath( './/*[@class="listing-headline"]/a/@href' ).extract()
        link = ['https:\\www.pistonheads.com' + i for i in link]

        for item in zip(timestamps,link,models,title,year,price,mileage,transmission):
            price_data = {
                    'timestamp' : item[0],
                    'link' :item[1],
                    'model' : item[2],
                    'title' : item[3],
                    'year' : year[4],
                    'price' : item[5],
                    'mileage' : item[6],
                    'transmission' :item[7]

            }
            yield price_data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have `'year' : year[4],` so yeah, it will give you always the same value.
2. Since you have 70 transmissions and 73 items, zip merges transmissions to items in wrong way. So, I offer you to do it in this way:

```py
class SuperScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ss22'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = 'https://www.pistonheads.com/classifieds?Category=used-cars&M=1044&ResultsPerPage=750'
        yield scrapy.Request(urls, self.parse_data)

    def parse_data( self, response ):
        model = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').get('')
        model = model.replace("Used ", "").replace(" cars for sale with PistonHeads", "")
        for row in response.xpath('//*[@class="ad-listing"]'):
            transmisson = row.xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "flaticon solid location-pin-4")]/following-sibling::text()').get('')
            mileage = row.xpath('.//*[contains(@class, "flaticon solid gauge-1")]/following-sibling::text()').get('')
            price_data = {
                    'timestamp': str(date.today()).split('.')[0],
                    'link': 'https://www.pistonheads.com' + row.xpath('.//*[@class="listing-headline"]/a/@href').get(''),
                    'model': model,
                    'title': row.xpath('.//*[@class="listing-headline"]//h3/text()').get('').strip(),
                    'year': row.xpath('.//*[@class="listing-headline"]//h3/text()').get(''),
                    'price': row.xpath('.//*[@class="price"]/text()').get('').strip(),
                    'mileage': mileage.replace(',', '').replace(' miles', '').strip(),
                    'transmission': transmisson.strip(),
            }
            yield price_data
```

Here we iterate by item, so we never miss whether transmission appears for this item or not.

Comment: thank you so much. I appreciate the time you put into this response.